# wait for child window in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to wait for the child window in selenium web driver

when I click on the submit button it leads me to child window and I assert the Url but sometimes the child window takes time to come
Currently using thread.sleep(4000)
**But this is the wrong way.**

```
    // parent window
    String subWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window
    // handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    String Current_Url = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    System.out.println("Current open Url in other Tab -->" + Current_Url);

    try {
        Assert.assertEquals("http://intelliview-dev.psi.psigroupinc.com/Reports/ReportView.aspx", Current_Url);
        logger.info("Assertion Passed");
        logger.info("User is able to login to My Account Application");
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        logger.info("Assertion Failed");
        logger.info("User Provide Invalid Username or Password");
        throw e;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe`.

Click on event which invoke window and then use below code and then use switch another window

Put the count as per your requirement

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

For that, you need to make sure that what would be the max time(Acceptable time limit) does the application takes to open that new window. 
Before that get the current window details using

```
String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Then wait for the new window using

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,AcceptableTimeLimit).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
```

Then switch to the new window using

```
Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator ite=allWindows.iterator();
while(ite.hasNext()){
    String popupHandle=ite.next().toString();
    if(!popupHandle.contains(parent_window)){
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        //perform your operations on New window
        //Then switch back to parent window
        driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);
       }
  }
```

Comment: kindly do not post the same answer which already been provided ..